# Is there a way to override the default .NET 6 validation message template?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

The default validation messages all end with a full stop and I want to remove this for every property validation message without having to add a custom ErrorMessage format for each validation attribute.

[image: .NET 6 validation messages]

I've tried looking at setting methods in `ModelBindingMessageProvider` when adding Mvc as part of my `Startup.cs` class. No success with this...

Comment: Does this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64339575/global-error-handler-including-model-binder-errors and here is an other reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 3):

The error message is come from `ModelError` in the `ModelState` but it doesn't have `set` method so we can't override the error message template(as far as I know). I have 2 ways to do it, first one is create a new `ModelError` instance so you can assing the error message what you want, second one is almost same as first one but you can keep the filed name in error message.

**Method 1**

```
builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = (actionContext) =>
    {
        foreach (var x in actionContext.ModelState)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < x.Value.Errors.Count; i++)
            {
                x.Value.Errors[i] = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelError("Your message here");
            }
        }

        var problemDetails = new ValidationProblemDetails(actionContext.ModelState);

        problemDetails.Type = options.ClientErrorMapping[400].Link;
        problemDetails.Title = "One or more validation errors occurred.";
        problemDetails.Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;

        return new BadRequestObjectResult(problemDetails);
    };
});
```

**Method 2**

```
builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = (actionContext) =>
    {
        var errorDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]>(StringComparer.Ordinal);
        var errorMessageTemplate = "Your message here, The field {0} is required";
        foreach (var keyModelStatePair in actionContext.ModelState)
        {
            var key = keyModelStatePair.Key;
            var errors = keyModelStatePair.Value.Errors;
            if (errors != null && errors.Count > 0)
            {
                if (errors.Count == 1)
                {
                    var errorMessage = errorMessageTemplate;
                    errorDictionary.Add(key, new[] { string.Format(errorMessage, key) });
                }
                else
                {
                    var errorMessages = new string[errors.Count];
                    for (var i = 0; i < errors.Count; i++)
                    {
                        errorMessages[i] = errorMessageTemplate;
                    }

                    errorDictionary.Add(key, errorMessages);
                }
            }
        }

        var errorModel = new
        {
            Type = options.ClientErrorMapping[400].Link,
            Title = "One or more validation errors occurred.",
            Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
            Errors = errorDictionary
        };
        return new BadRequestObjectResult(errorModel);
    };
});
```